# Can Scrapy be utilized as a realtime wrapper?

Tags: python, screen-scraping, wrapper, scrapy, word-wrap

I was hoping someone might be able to provide some insights into the feasibility of utilizing the scrapy python framework for creating a realtime wrapper.

To clarify my definition of the term "wrapper" in this context let me describe my situation... I was hoping to use scrapy to essentially script a solution to allow a user to  execute a search query on a website which in turn would call a scrapy spider in real-time within which that spider is told to:

1. login to a 3rd party write
2. execute the users search query
3. retrieve only the actual html results for the returned query by extracting the resulting html content by specifying the unique result set container class and/or xpath).
4. modify the extracted html results (by either reforming the html and/or injecting a new header/footer or css elements). 5) and finally returning the modified html results in real-time so the html can be directly injected into the original domain all by being transparent to the user.

I should point out that I am familiar with writing scrapy spider for large scale crawling in bulk but I am less familiar with the prospect or feasibility of being able to use it to construct a real-time type of "wrapper".

If anyone has any insight, advice or examples which illustrate a similar situation I would greatly appreciate it. CH

Answer (score 1):

You may try HTQL browser interface for python at http://htql.net/.  An example to Bing search in real time is:

```
import htql;
a=htql.Browser(); 
b=a.goUrl("http://www.bing.com/");
c=a.goForm("<form>1", {"q":"test"});
for d in htql.HTQL(c[0], "<a (tx like '%test%')>"): 
    print(d);

e=a.click("<a (tx like '%test%' and not (href like '/search%'))>1");
```

It can be coupled with IRobotSoft scraper to do everything visually, by changing the browser to:

```
a=htql.Browser(2);
```

More details can be found from this manual http://htql.net/htql-python-manual.pdf or ask at http://irobotsoft.org/bb/

Comment: thanks for the info but could you point to some type of example links which discuss this approach further in terms of my specific desired situation?